# Subsurface black edge

Tags: modeling, rendering, subdivision-surface

I have a surface with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and when I render it in Cycles, there is a black edge at the edge of the surface:

[image]

If I render it without *Subdivision Surface* it looks like this:

[image]

What could be the reason and how can I stop this?

EDIT:

After adding the *Edge Split* modifier as [suggested](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63318/20508) by [Shady Puck](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/20508/shady-puck), the result looks as expected:

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the .blend file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can minimize this by increasing the *Subsurf* levels and eliminate it with an *Edge Split* modifier. A clever combination of both may suit you.

*Sorry for low quality:*

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding  _Edge Split_ modifier solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you have smooth normals.  Either set those faces to flat shading or enable Auto Smooth under Mesh Data.

Comment: could you explain a little bit what is the difference to splitting the edges? Do you mean it is because I **don't** have smooth normals?

Comment: @Noidea _Smooth_ shading your mesh can lead to this blackening of the edges...something I forgot to mention, but Xtremity remembered.